# how to add append hostname in shell

Tags: shell, hostname

i want to copy the file content in to another file with hostname. kindly suggest

```
more status.txt  > /users/home/xbbj7fc/one.txt
```

the about command gives output **webserver is UP** . 
But i want to add  **webserver is UP in $hostname**  to one.txt. Can you suggest ?

Comment: `more` is (exclusively) for displaying content to a screen. Redirecting its output anywhere but the screen doesn't make sense.

Comment: BTW, when you say `$hostname`, do you mean the current hostname, or the content of a variable named `hostname`?

Comment: It's `echo "$(<status.txt) in $hostname" >one.txt` in the former case, `echo "$(<status.txt) in $(hostname)" >one.txt` in the latter. Note that `$(<status.txt)` should may need to be the less-efficient formulation `$(cat status.txt)` if your shell isn't actually bash.